# c# Request.Form to string and back to Request.Form

Tags: c#, request.form

I'm facing this problem. I pass the request form as a string to a webservice, and then inside it I'm trying to fetch the data inside that string. I guess I could work it out searching for each substring but I wonder if there's a way of creating back a collection the way the Request.Form is.

Thanks!!

You're right davenewza, sorry for that

The string will look basically like this

```
title_1=Mr&initials_1=James&surname_1=Smith&title_2=Mr&initials_2=Harry&surname_2=Smith&Address=TestAddress&City=Surrey&
```

although it will be too long to paste it entirely it will be this way, just the result of pass ToString a RequestForm, and what I would like to get is the actual value of the initials_1, surname_1, initials_2, Address..... so the easiest way would be if I could transform it back to a Dictionary, isn't it? but don't know if it's possible

Comment: Supply code please.  It gives us context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do it

```
string request = ...
Dictionary<string,string> param = new Dictionary<string,string>();
request.Split('&')
       .Select(o => o.Split('='))
       .ToList()
       .ForEach(p => param.Add(p[0],p[1])
);
```

But you have to be sure only parameter appears only once. Otherwise, you could do p => param[p[0]] = p[1], then you would replace previous versions... If you want to keep them all, you'll need a Dictionary>